# Redirect all the mysql requests to other DB server

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-proxy

I have a staging server on AWS where my web application is running.the application uses Dedicated Database server(mysql/linux) from other provider. i would like to spin a new server on a AWS that should act like a proxy server to connect with my Dedicated Database server. 
please advise me how can i achieve.

Comment: This is not programming related. At least I don't assume you want to write something that does this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can proxy the traffic with HAproxy, you can have one DB in active mode and one in passive mode, when ready to cut over you take the active one offline and ha will start sending requests to the other DB server.

Additionally, HAproxy will allow you to send traffic to certain DB servers depending on a variety of criteria, like the source IP. So some web apps send to one DB and others send to another.

HA proxy is very lightweight, we use it and run hundreds of thousands of requests a day without any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MaxScale from MariaDB. it a DB proxy. the can do all this and more..

https://mariadb.com/products/mariadb-maxscale